# Should username index column be "index" or "unique"

Tags: mysql

My question is simple or (stupid).
Everywhere i read says username column index type should be "unique" but i discovered Wordpress "user_login" is "index" instead of "unique".
[image: WP user index]
I felt the reason WP has it that way is because whenever a user tries to register, a check "must" be made (whether the indexed username column is "unique" or "index").
So i want to know:

1. Is there any extra overhead when using "unique"
2. Since i will "always" check if a user exists at registration point, is there still need to use "unique" intead of just "index"

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269293/is-there-any-performance-difference-between-unique-index-and-index-with-the-same

Comment: As for "always", the point of constraint in DB level is it's guaranteed to be valid regardless if someone forgot to check with different client, direct query to the DB, etc

Comment: @Martheen I got better now. Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I would also add that whether a column is unique or not is a business decision, not a programming one.